# How to use WeightNormalization wrapper for LocallyConnected2D layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, normalization, keras-layer

I'm trying to use the [`tfa.layers.WeightNormalization`](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/layers/WeightNormalization) wrapper around a [`tf.layers.LocallyConnected2D`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LocallyConnected2D) layer like so:

```
from tensorflow_addons.layers import WeightNormalization
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.ones((1, 32, 32, 3))
x = WeightNormalization(tf.keras.layers.LocallyConnected2D(3, 3))(x)
```

It gives the following error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

For the record, this does work with a `Conv2D` layer. Any idea how to get this working with a `LocallyConnected2D` layer?

Comment: you missed data_init=False... WeightNormalization(tf.keras.layers.LocallyConnected2D(3, 3), data_init=False)(x)

Comment: That solves the issue! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From comments

```
from tensorflow_addons.layers import WeightNormalization
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.ones((1, 32, 32, 3))
x = WeightNormalization(tf.keras.layers.LocallyConnected2D(3, 3), data_init=False)(x)
```

(paraphrased from Marco Cerliani)